# List references to a C symbol given the file where it's defined

Tags: c, symbols, ctags, cscope, opengrok

I have a project with files `foo1.h` and `foo2.h`, both of which declare a function `int foo();`.

The project contains a much bigger set of C files, where some of them include `foo1.h` or `foo2.h` and use `foo()`.

Is there a way to list the references to a symbol using `cscope` or similar, given the file where it is defined?

I have tried `cscope -d -L -0 foo`, but it lists *all* references to `foo()`, defined in either `.h` file.

Is it possible to pass an argument with the definition location of the symbol, so that the result is a list of references to *only that* symbol?

Comment: _"both of which define a function"_, do you mean both of which declare `int foo();`, i.e. a prototype?  Typically functions are _defined_ in a `.c` file.

Comment: @ryyker You are correct.

Comment: I haven't tried but you could try to first find all relevant source files e.g. by `find . | xargs grep -l 'include.*foo1\.h'` to create a list  of all relevant files and then use cscope's `-I namefile` option

Comment: _"Is there a way to list all references to a symbol using cscope or similar"_...  Tools like [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/) may be what you are looking for

Comment: you can create a custom addon to cppcheck.

Comment: You want to check out ctags / etags.

Comment: "Is there a way to list all references" ... "but it lists all references" Looks like it does exactly what you want.